# How do I set my OpenAI model before creating a conversation in dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net-core, openai-api

I am currently using the OpenAI_API dotnet package to create a conversation, append the user input and get a response from Chatbot as shown below:

```
var openAi = new OpenAIAPI(new APIAuthentication(
    "secret-key"
));

var conversation = openAi.Chat.CreateConversation();

var input = "This is where I set my prompt?";

conversation.AppendUserInput(input);
var response = await conversation.GetResponseFromChatbotAsync();
return Ok(response);
```

The default model that is being used is gpt-3.5-turbo. I want to change this to use gpt-4-32k. How can I do this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default OpenAI model this way:

```
var chat = api.Chat.CreateConversation();
chat.Model = Model.GPT4_32k_Context;
```